# How to display Autocomplete suggestions only after Enter is pressed?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I'd like to show autocomplete suggestions only after the user presses the Enter key.

After reading the [api docs](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete), I suspect I need to overwrite the `search` [event](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-search) or the `change` one, however I am unclear how to. In particular, the `search` event is:

> Triggered before a search is performed, after minLength and delay are met. If canceled, then no request will be started and no items
>   suggested.

What I'd like to do is cancel the event unless enter is pressed. How do I do this in the init function below?

```
$(".selector").on("autocompletechange", function(event, ui) {});
```

Or is there another better way to do this?

Comment: you want to display autocomplete after enter key press?

Comment: Yes, exactly - ONLY after enter key press

Comment: you need to change jQuery UI lib

Comment: How exactly should I change the JQuery UI lib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to alter your jquery lib events in order to catch the event of enter key and perform your functionality.In this function only enter key will open dropdown and the rest events will be disabled.

```
$(".selector").autocomplete({
                keypress: function (event, ui) {
                    if (event.which == 13) {
                        console.log("Key Pressed");
                    }
                    else
                        return false;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be let the onchange event be called every time, but you specifically fetch the details when **`Enter`** key is pressed. You can detect the key pressed from the event. Below is a sample -

```
function(event, ui) {
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        //write code to populate the Autocomplete
    }
}
```